# Encoding class style attributes with special characters

Tags: javascript, css, encoding, getelementbyid

I am try to populate two svg elements with style attributes. One with strokedashoffset and the other with transform: rotate. This is my expected css:

```
<circle class="progressbar-line-timer" id="timerOffset" 
style="strokedashoffset: 76.1942px;" r="48.5" cx="50" cy ="50" 
/>

<circle class="progressbar-marker-timer" id="timerRotate"  
style="transform: rotate(270deg);" r="6" cx="50" cy="1.5" />
```

I have created a function to calculate those two values.

I am attempting to use getElementById() to populate the values. I have assigned an ID's to the svg elements.

```
<circle class="progressbar-line-timer" id="timerOffset" 
r="48.5" cx="50" cy ="50" />
<circle class="progressbar-marker-timer" id="timerRotate"  
r="6" cx="50" cy="1.5" />
```

Because these style attributes have special characters - dashes, colons, and parens, I am using encodeURI to encode the string for I read that it can handle special characters.

I cannot seem to get the correct values to encode correctly. I am getting this error on the document.getElementById("timerOffset") statement:

```
VM88:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of 
null
    at <anonymous>:31:47
(anonymous) @ VM88:31
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
    //calculated values rotateTimer 
    //                  offsetTimer 

    // using escape to recognize the double quotes
    timerURIComprotateHold = ('\"stroke-dashoffset: '+rotateTimer+'\"')
    var timerURIComprotate = encodeURI(timerURIComprotateHold);
    console.log('timerURIComprotate '+timerURIComprotate );

    // erroring on this statement        

document.getElementById("timerOffset").style.timerURIComprotate;  


    // calculated value of timerURIComprotate %22stroke-dashoffset:%20125.99999999999999px;%22
```

Isn’t %22 quotes and %20 a space and shouldn’t this work?

I’ve tried encodeURIComponent as well with no luck.
Is there another encoding method I can try?
The encoding needs to be to handle parens too for they are in the style attributes of the second element i want to style.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript isn't successfully getting an element by its ID, it may be that your JavaScript is being loaded before the element has been rendered. That is: at the time your JavaScript is being run, the browser doesn't "know about" the `<circle>` elements.

Web browsers execute your code line-by-line, going from top-to-bottom and left-to-right of the code you wrote, so if your JavaScript is in a `<script>` tag in line 5 of your HTML, and your `<circle>` element is in line 32, your web browser is going to run the JavaScript before it has read the `<circle>` HTML. That's why it's saying it can't modify the `style` "of null" -- it's trying to modify something that doesn't exist yet.

To prevent this, you need to tell the browser to not run the JavaScript until the DOM's content -- all the HTML elements -- have loaded. This is usually done in one of two ways:

- `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')` (see examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), or
- Putting your JavaScript in `<script>` tag *after* the rest of your HTML, usually right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually have the javascript  at the very bottom of the code right before the closing body tag. Thanks though :)